# Is there a way to read HTTP response body as Integer Array in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, httpresponse

The Android app I am working on receives arrays from the server that are over 2 million long and the app needs to use them as integer array and it takes quite long to convert an array that long from byte array to integer array

The Android app uses OkHTTP to send request and receive responses from the server
What I want is to **read the response body as **integer array****

Comment: Probably the worst way of receiving a large amount data (esp. millions). But, could you show a snippet of the body? I would like to see the opening and ending characters exactly. are the just enclosed in [] or is it a json with an array as part of its data?

Comment: Yes, it's enclosed in [], not a json with an array field. This is a snippet: [-82, -21, -20, -78, -17, -34...] What I did in the end is I used sequence.